# Redirect or meta refresh not working on chrome mobile browser

Tags: php, html

I'm using a simple html page to get a text input and post the data to a php script. The php script does not output any content and it runs in the background. Once the php script is executed, i would like to return to the html page.

I have the following in my html page.

```
<form action="call_api.php" method="post">
```

Then I have tried each of the following in my php file to redirect to the html page.

```
header("refresh:0;url=index.html");
die;
```

```
header("Location: index.html");
```

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=http://website.com/index.html" />
```

The problem i'm facing is, the redirect works perfectly on desktop browsers. However the redirect does not work on my mobile chrome browser despite all attempts using above redirect mechanisms. After submitting the form on mobile browser, it does nothing.

**Versions:**
PHP 5.5.38 / 
Apache/2.2.15 (Unix)

Comment: Try putting `<meta>` tag inside `<head>` tag. I do not see anything wrong with your code. Also try private mode on your mobile browser or clear cookies and cache.

Comment: header("Location: index.html") MUST be the first thing that is sent to the browser

Comment: There was a mistake in html code. The submit button input was not inside form tag. Kept it inside form tag and it works on mobile. Very strange behavior to see the difference in desktop and mobile for same code.